# Can we use asp.net to create backend service in stripe?

Tags: android

I am creating a payment project(Android) in which i want to send token to server bt i am bit confused that webservice for stripe build in asp.net or not.Please answer any one as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official docs available in stripe api documentation for .net .Try to use PHP as back-end service or use these links to use .net in stripe(Not official)

[link1](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net)

[link2](https://cmatskas.com/processing-payments-on-your-site-using-stripe-and-net/)